# How would I edit the Laravel Nova indexQuery for a Resource to only show records through multiple relationships?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

firstly thank you in advance.

I have the following `Models` , `User` , `Location`, `Listing`, `Offer`.

The relationships are:
User Model:

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Location::class);
}
```

Location Model:

```
public function listings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Listing::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Listing Model:

```
public function offers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Offer::class);
    }

    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }
```

Offer Model:

```
public function listing()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Listing::class);
    }
```

In my Offer Resourse I would like to show only the offers that belongTo the listings that in turn belongsTo the location that in turn belongTo the authenticated user. I have tried the following.

public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{

```
$user = Auth::user();
if ($user->is_admin === 1){
    return $query;
}elseif($user->is_admin === 0) {
    return $user->location->listings->offers;
}
```

}

But get an error Property [offers] does not exist on this collection instance. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this.
More information here on querying relationship existence:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

```php
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query) {
    $user = Auth::user();

    if (!$user->is_admin) {
        $query = $query->whereHas('listings.location.user', function ($builder) use ($user) {
            return $builder->where('id', $user->id);
        });
    }

    return $query;
}
```

The reason you are getting the "Property does not exist" error is due to you not pulling it from database.
Two alternative solutions include

- Querying them separately: `...->listings()->offers()`
- Eager loading: `->with(['location.listings.offers']);`